# Is there any way to find GPUImageFilter correspond CIFilter?

Tags: ios, gpuimage, cifilter, gpuimagestillcamera

I wrote my iOS image processing app using CIFilters.
Now I am going to replace the filters as GPUImageFilters.
But I don't know how can I find the corresponding GPUImageFilters from previous CIFilters?
Is there any way to find exactly same or similar GPUImageFilters with CIFilters?

Some of CIFilter names are as follows.

- CIPhotoEffectInstant    CIPhotoEffectTransfer    CISepiaTone 
  CISRGBToneCurveToLinear  CISharpenLuminance  CIPixellate 
  CIGaussianBlur ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you could look at [the names of the filters contained within GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage):

- CISepiaTone -> GPUImageSepiaFilter
- CISharpenLuminance -> GPUImageSharpenFilter
- CIPixellate -> GPUImagePixellateFilter
- CIGaussianBlur -> GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter

Many of the filters were patterned after what Core Image provides. There isn't always a one-to-one mapping, and some filters are present in one framework and missing within the other.

GPUImage allows you to create custom filters by combining others or writing your own fragment shaders, so for the remainder you can build your own filters to replace those from Core Image.